# How to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\int^x_2 (\ln t)^{-1} dt \right) \big/ (x\ /\ln x)=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int^x_2\frac{1}{\ln t}dt}{\frac{x}{\ln x}}=1.$$

I thought to use L'Hospital's rule, but for that both denominator and numerator should go to infinity. I am not convinced my self for that.

**My attempt:**

By applying L'Hospital's rule, we get
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1/\ln x}{\frac{\ln x-1}{(\ln x)^2}}.$$
Here, for denominator I again use L'Hospital's rule, to get $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{\ln x-1}=1.$$
Am I right? And what are reasons for the numerator to tend to infinity?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to check whether numerator goes to infinity. Denominator tending to infinity is sufficient for the application of L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Sir Are you mean after log x shift to numerator na?

Comment: I am talking of the original expression (where there is an integral in numerator).

Comment: The case $0/0$ for L'Hospital's Rule is popular, but the other case is $\text{anything} /\infty$ which is not so popular.

Comment: Sir I am Knowing the rule that if both Numerator and demominator both goes to 0 or infity then only we can apply lhopital .Is I am wrong @ParamanandSingh?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir Is it possible to get some reference of proof? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Just note that case $\infty/\infty$ is already included in $\text{anything} /\infty$ so it is best not to check for numerator tending to $\infty$.

Comment: Check proof in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int^x_2\frac{1}{\ln t}\,\mathrm dt$ tends to $+\infty$ because $\;\ln t<t$ for all $t$, so if $t>1$,
$$\frac1{\ln t}>\frac 1t,\;\text{whence }\;\int^x_2\frac{1}{\ln t}\,\mathrm dt\ge \int^x_2\frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm dt=\ln x-\ln 2.,$$

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir. Is my Application of L'Hopital rule is right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. In my opinion, the second application of L'Hospital is unnecessary.